# Создать все комбинации списка

Tags: python

Имеется список:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Как пересобрать массив, что бы элементы стояли во всех возможных комбинациях?

```
print(l) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(l) # [1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
print(l) # [1, 2, 5, 3, 4]
```

итд

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

```
import itertools

l = [1,2,3,4,5]
for x in itertools.permutations(l):
    print(x)
```